# What is the boundary of restorable thermal expansion?

Tags: solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity, solid-mechanics

As every book indicates, thermal expansion is a linear process
$\frac{\Delta L}{L}=\alpha \Delta T$.

Upon heating an object the result is thermal expansion. If we cool it down it is restored its original volume.

Is there a boundary beyond which the expansion is not restorable?

Comment: Certainly when irreversible phase transitions start to occur. Worst case the material will melt or decompose, but there are material which change their crystal structure before that. Steel, I believe, is one of those, but you would have to look at the phase diagrams. The linear temperature dependence is a pretty crude approximation for many materials and should not be relied on, if any level of precision is required.

Comment: Melting and decomposing is very obvious.

Comment: For real materials thermal expansion is not actually linear across a broad temperature range.  It is a useful approximation, but beware "far" from room temperature. For an initially stress-free single crystal, heated and cooled slowly enough, I think the primary issue would be creep and dislocation nucleation at high thermal point defect populations. (One could argue that dislocations should dissolve on slow-enough cooling and any net deformation would still be creep).